# How to create a getter by returning a function?

Tags: javascript

Getters cannot accept arguments, but you can do a "workaround" of returning a function from the getter and thus use an argument:

```
  get _getLabelByFieldName(): (fieldName: FieldName) => string {
    return (fieldName) => fieldToSectionMap[fieldName].title;
  }
```

However with this trick, I won't be able to access the `this` keyword:

```
  get _getNumberOfAvailableColumns(): (rowIndex: number) => number {
    return (rowIndex) => {
      const newData = this.form[rowIndex]; // this.form is not defined
```

I can re-write it like this:

```
 public _getNumberOfAvailableColumns = (): ((rowIndex: number) => number) => {
    return (rowIndex) => {
      .....
```

But now it's not a getter anymore. Is there a way to write the function as a getter and have access to `this` ?

Comment: _"Getters cannot accept arguments"_ - sounds like you need a function then?

Comment: use function definition instead of arrow function bcz arrow function has no this they take from outer lexical environment in your case from outer function.

Comment: In my first example it's a getter that does receive an argument by this workaround I mentioned, I'd like to still use a getter if possible, do you think it's not possible (in the second example) ?

Comment: I'm not sure it matters whether it's possible, because (imo) it's the wrong tool.

Comment: @sir-haver *why* do you want to use a getter? A normal method seems to be the right tool.

Comment: "*I won't be able to access the `this` keyword*" - I don't see anything wrong there, the `this` inside the arrow function will be the `this` on which the getter was accessed. If you have trouble with this, please provide a more complete [mcve] including the whole class/object definition and the call of the "method".